# Merge sort a list of integers

Tags: python, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel

This code is meant to sort a list of integers using merge sort.

I'm doing this to improve my style and to improve my knowledge of fundamental algorithms/data structures for an upcoming coding interview.

```
def merge_sort(l):
    if len(l) == 0 or len(l) == 1:
        return

    mid = len(l) // 2
    left = l[:mid]
    right = l[mid:]
    merge_sort(left)
    merge_sort(right)
    merge(l, left, right)


def merge(l, left, right):
    l_ind, r_ind, ind = 0, 0, 0
    left_len, right_len, l_len = len(left), len(right), len(l)

    while l_ind < left_len and r_ind < right_len:
        if left[l_ind] < right[r_ind]:
            l[ind] = left[l_ind]
            l_ind += 1
            ind += 1
        else:
            l[ind] = right[r_ind]
            r_ind += 1
            ind += 1

    if l_ind < left_len and r_ind >= right_len:
        while ind < l_len:
            l[ind] = left[l_ind]
            l_ind += 1
            ind += 1
    elif l_ind >= left_len and r_ind < right_len:
        while ind < l_len:
            l[ind] = right[r_ind]
            r_ind += 1
            ind += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Get rid of some `len`

```
left_len, right_len, l_len = len(left), len(right), len(l)
```

Get rid of these, they don't do anything in terms of readability. They also are unnecessary, the `len` call is [**not** `O(n)` it is simply `O(1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115329/667648).

## (Maybe) a library?

Also, although Rosetta code isn't always the most stylistic source, if you look [at their solution](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#Python), the use a pre-built `merge`. As you say you are "reinventing the wheel", maybe you don't *want* to do that but something to consider in the future.

## Naming

```
l_ind, r_ind ...
```

I would write those out in full as `left_ind` and `right_ind`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know that `len()` was `O(1)`. That'll definitely neaten my code up. All the suggestions were good. Thanks again :)